# How to group values from a list with Java Stream API (groupingBy collector)?

Tags: java, datetime, java-stream, date

I have list of `Entry` objects. `Entry` is a:

```
class Entry {
   private final Date date;
   private final String value;

   // constructor
   // getters
}
```

I need to group these entries *by day*. For example,

```
2011-03-21 09:00 VALUE1
2011-03-21 09:00 VALUE2
2011-03-22 14:00 VALUE3
2011-03-22 16:00 VALUE4
2011-03-21 16:00 VALUE5
```

Should be grouped:

```
2011-03-21
    VALUE1
    VALUE2
    VALUE5

2011-03-22
    VALUE3
    VALUE4
```

I want to get a `Map<Date, List<Entry>>`. **How can I get this using the Stream API (groupingBy collector)?**

My attempt below:

```
final Map<Date, List<Entry>> entries =
        list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(request -> {
        final Calendar ogirinal = Calendar.getInstance();
        ogirinal.setTime(request.getDate());

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ogirinal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, ogirinal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, ogirinal.get(Calendar.YEAR));

        return cal.getTime();
    }));
```

Output:

```
2011-03-21
    VALUE1
2011-03-21
    VALUE2
2011-03-22
    VALUE3
    VALUE4
2011-03-21
    VALUE5
```

Comment: show what you have tried so far. Also if you are on Java 8 or above, then why not using the new [java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)?

Comment: "I need to group this entries by *day*." - Day of the week?  Day of the month?  Day of the year?

Comment: Also, tell us what output is your code giving?

Comment: @JacobG. By day of the month, month and year, like in example

Comment: Ha, funny. You need to set the `cal`'s time (hour, minute, second, milis) to 0. Otherwise your element will each be a few nanoSecond apart, only sometimes two will end up with the same time due to the timer's inaccuracies. Try using the newer `LocalDate` instead of `Calendar`, it makes creating date-only timestamps much easier.

Comment: Given this is Java 8, you should avoid using `Date` objects.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Again don't understand why you are using `java.util.Date` when you can use [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) for example. But here goes my attempt:

```
Map<Date, List<Entry>> entries = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e ->
    // easier way to truncate the date
    Date.from(e.getDate().toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)))
);
```

[**DEMO**](https://ideone.com/4MwwHk)

Answer (score 14):

You have to truncate the date values, as they may be different up to the millisecond:

```
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS;

final Map<Instant, List<Entry>> entries =
    list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(request -> 
        request.getDate().toInstant().truncatedTo(DAYS)));
```

Comment: This gives grouping by days in UTC. If this is what is desired, it’s a very fine solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is pretty much the right way to go, but your entries end up in different groups because the `Calendar` objects you return all have slightly different timestamps. This is because you do not set hour/minute/... to 0. Only when two of the calendars have the same time by coincidence (due to timer inaccuracies for example) two entries will end up in the same group.

Use something like this to group instead:

```
LocalDate.fromDateFields(request.getDate());
```

`LocalDate` makes creating date-only timestamps much easier than `Calendar`. This snippet uses joda time's  `LocalDate`, but Java's own is only slightly longer.

Comment: Worth to mention that you refer to [`org.joda.time.LocalDate`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) here as there isn't any `LocalDate::fromDateFields` in [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I have to admit that I did not realize it at first. I think it's time to finally kick joda time out of our class path. As the other answers already show how to use Java LocalDate, I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to group by date (day, month and year), you can discard the time (hour, minutes, seconds). As you're using Java 8, just convert the `java.util.Date` to a `java.time.LocalDate`:

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Entry>> entries = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(request ->
         request.getDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate()));
```

Just some background: a `Date` represents a specific point in time, the [number of milliseconds since Unix epoch](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/), while a `LocalDate` represents only a day/month/year date, without any notion of timezone.

To properly convert a `Date` to a `LocalDate`, I set it to the JVM default timezone (using `toInstant().atZone()`) and then get only the local part (`toLocalDate()`).

You could also make your design simpler, changing the `Entry` class to have a `LocalDate` field, if possible. You're using Java 8, and unless you have a good reason to use the old API ("legacy code", "my boss doesn't want", etc), it's better to start using `java.time` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. You are facing the issue because, while initiating the `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()` object, the minutes, seconds, hours, and all other fields are also getting set which is causing trouble in the grouping. (The two timestamps aren't *actually same* for them to be grouped together.)

You need to clear all the other fields except the ones that you are setting so that they are essentially same.

You need to set all other fields except `DAY_OF_MONTH`,`MONTH`,`YEAR` to 0. Use [`Calender.clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear()) for the same.

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, ogirinal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, ogirinal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, ogirinal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

This should clear the problem.

Comment: I wonder, too. I think this is the cause of the problem, and I like your answer. Didn't really know the `Calendar.clear()` method.

Answer (score 2):

There are many good and correct answers already. Still I should like to contribute my take. Take the full step into using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, by declaring your date field for example a `LocalDateTime`. You will probably want to change its name at the same time:

```
private final LocalDateTime dateTime;
```

Fit the `Entry` class with a convenience method for getting the date only:

```
public LocalDate getDateWithoutTimeOfDay() {
    return dateTime.toLocalDate();
}
```

Now the rest is really simple:

```
    final Map<LocalDate, List<Entry>> entries =
            list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getDateWithoutTimeOfDay));

    // print the result
    entries.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getKey());
        e.getValue().forEach(v -> System.out.println("    " + v.getValue()));
        System.out.println();
    });
```

This printed:

```
2011-03-22
    VALUE3
    VALUE4

2011-03-21
    VALUE1
    VALUE2
    VALUE5
```

Since the map returned from the grouping isn’t sorted, there’s no guarantee about the order of the dates in the printout, but the grouping is as you desired.